# Is there any way to edit or change the email in cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

There occurred a mismatch when I had inserted email address of the user when signed up, in my db email address are in lower case but in cognito it's in upper case. Is there any way which I can convert those to lower case in cognito.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can edit this data by using: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html

or using awscli with: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-update-user-attributes.html

If you would like to insert Email lower case to Cognito later after sign up. You should use above API on PostConfirmation Lambda Trigger hook to convert Email because there is no way to transform email in Pre-Signup Lambda Trigger hook.

Hope this help.

Comment: It should be possible to modify the event before returning it to cognito with the email lower cased. I haven't tested this.